# Flutter Architecture for present and future

Tags: flutter, architecture, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

hi i am a newbie in Coding by self leaning,just kickstarted with flutter development,done a couple of projects,while attending interviews,each one of them is asking about different architectures,seeing lot of architecture names TDD,clean architecture etc,i am bit confused, can somebody please explain which is top architecture ,how to select architectures based on  projects,somebody please guide me by explaining why architecture selection is so much important,which is top,or any reference videos or docs might be useful

Comment: You choose Bloc architecture if you are using bloc state management, and for TDD and others pattern you follow Uncle Bob's clean arch. and Design Pattern by GOF.

Answer (score 1):

If you develop Flutter Project,
I can recommend the architecture that is presented by Felix Angelov (BLoC author) in his tutorials - [link](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/)

Quick summary:

1. Use BLoC as a state management,
2. Split the code into repositories (packages),
3. Separate the logic from widgets,
4. Divide the whole project into 3 layers (Presentation Layer, Business Layer, Data Layer),
5. Provide tests (do not merge without 100% tests coverage)

Comment: for getx state management?